# Using Redcarpet with LiveReload

Tags: macos, haml, markdown, redcarpet, livereload

From what I've been reading about Markdown filters, I'd like to use RedCarpet as my filter in HAML. However, I'm using LiveReload , and apparently, currently it supports only RDiscount, RPeg-markdown, Maruku and BlueCloth.

Can anyone tell me how to make LiveReload use RedCarpet? If it's not possible, which one of those other four filters is a good recommendation (most actively developed, safest, has a greater community backing)?

Comment: Asking for the "best" of something is a very good way to have your question closed. Stack Overflow doesn't deal in subjective opinions.

Comment: That is why I defined characteristics for “best”, but thank you for the warning. Edited accordingly.